# Handling Flickering with Theme Change and Local Storage in Next.js with Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a feature for dynamically changing themes (light/dark) in a `Next.js` application using `Ant Design`. I've successfully implemented the theme switch
using a `useState` hook and a toggle switch. However, I'm struggling with storing the theme preference in `local storage` without causing a flicker on page load.

Here's the relevant part of my layout.tsx:

```
"use client";

import { Layout, ConfigProvider, Switch, theme as antdTheme } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";
const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onChange = (checked: boolean) => {
    setTheme((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        algorithm: theme ? antdTheme.darkAlgorithm : antdTheme.defaultAlgorithm,
      }}
    >
      <Layout>
        <Header></Header>
        <Content>
          <Switch defaultChecked onChange={onChange} />
          {children}
        </Content>
        <Footer>Footer</Footer>
      </Layout>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}
```

The switch works fine, but I'm unsure how to properly store and retrieve the theme setting from `local storage`.

Using `useEffect` to read the `local storage` value causes flickering on page load. To avoid this, I considered adding a conditional render like this:

```
const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
});

return (
    {mounted && <ConfigProvider>...</ConfigProvider>}
```

However, conditioning the rendering of the main `ConfigProvider` node doesn't seem like the best practice. Is there a more appropriate way to handle this scenario in a `Next.js` app? How can I effectively store and retrieve the theme setting from `local storage` without causing a flicker on page load?

Any suggestions or best practices for handling this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with "flickering"? Initial theme is light but then it switches to dark after loading stored theme?

Comment: Yes. On server side I have to pass something to ConfigProvider. When you pass different value than is stored in `local storage`, page changes mode during client side first render and flickers.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to prevent this flick because react will only access localStorage after first render so theme will be default then react will fetch saved theme and then change to right theme. I'll follow your answer because I'm also looking for this